# Python "exec /usr/local/bin/python3: exec format error" on Docker while using Apple M1 Max

Tags: linux, docker, apple-m1, python-3.8

My docker images were working fine as soon as I moved to my new Mac M1 Max. Even with my M1 Max, I have installed docker and successfully created image, and pushed to AWS ECR. Now when I'm running that image, it doesn't run but throws an error

```
exec /usr/local/bin/python3: exec format error
```

My Dockerfile looks like below but no luck yet. The same error everytime. I know that it's not straight forward to built docker images on Mac M1 Max and run them but in many StackOverflow answers I found that the below addition `--platform=linux/arm64` helps but not in my case yet.

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.8-slim-buster
# FROM --platform=linux/arm64 python:3.8-slim-buster (tried this one as well)
# FROM --platform=linux/arm64/v8 python:3.8-slim-buster (tried this one as well)


WORKDIR /project
COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN apt-get -qq update 
RUN pip3 --quiet install --requirement requirements.txt \
         --force-reinstall --upgrade

COPY . .
```

Comment: `--platform=linux/amd64` might have something to do with it. M1 is a arm cpu.

Comment: Used --platform=linux/arm64 as well but no luck yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got it working by just adding `as build`.
So the first line will look like

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.8-slim-buster as build
```

I'm not exactly sure what's the difference between the above line and the one I was using earlier but some `as build` is mentioned in the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/#build-multi-arch-images-with-buildx). Now it works fine

Comment: this solved same issue, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Google Vertex AI and ARM-Macbook.

I built a ML training container locally using the `docker build` and the container ran the mock tests without any errors and also the actual Python code worked well, when executed from terminal.

However, **the container did not work when used in the Vertex AI** training job, and resulted two vague error codes: `exec /usr/local/bin/python: exec format error` and `The replica workerpool0-0 exited with a non-zero status of 1`

The problem was solved using the provided solution,
by adding
`FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.10 AS build`
in the beginning of the Dockerfile.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact issue as @Rasmus Haapaniemi, but I was using [`LocalModel.build_cpr_model`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/1.19.1/google.cloud.aiplatform.prediction.LocalModel#google_cloud_aiplatform_prediction_LocalModel_build_cpr_model) to create a prediction container.

Amazingly, I was able to pass the entire text above, in my case `"--platform=linux/amd64 python:3.11 AS build"`, to the `base_image` argument of `build_cpr_model`, and it gets passed directly to the `FROM` statement of the Dockerfile under the hood, and solves the problem.